# Dictionary comprehension out of list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following example:

```
my_list = [(1, 'old', 'new'),
           (2, 'old2', 'new2'),
           (3, 'old3', 'new3')]

{x[1]:y[2] for x,y in zip(my_list,my_list)}
```

```
{'old': 'new', 'old2': 'new2', 'old3': 'new3'}
```

I was wondering if I can achieve the same thing without `zipping` the same iterable `my_list` twice.

Comment: That zip is weird :D Why? The `x` and `y` there will just have the same values. After all, both are just from the same list.

Comment: Early morning I guess, slipped on this :D

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a zip at all, just a dictionary comprehension

```
{x[1]:x[2] for x in my_list}
```

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I did not try that.

Answer (score 1):

Why using `zip`, ty this;

```
my_list = [(1, 'old', 'new'),
           (2, 'old2', 'new2'),
           (3, 'old3', 'new3')]

{x[1]:x[2] for x in my_list}
```